# Swift UICollectionView Cell not stretched

Tags: swift

I have created Carousel using uicollectioview in swift xcode. I don't know the output is something wrong. The cell is not stretched or fit the screen. I want to show 1 cell at once.
[image]

Comment: you have to use aspect to fit in your storyboard or programmatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cell.imageview.contentMode = aspectToFit
```

Or if you use storyboard change it to aspectToFit

Comment: I did change to aspectToFit in the storyboard Sir, still the same.